# Unsure if purchase or not a codesign certificate for custom xinput dll

Tags: c++, directx, code-signing, xinput

Hi I like to create a custom version of xinput1_3.dll in visual c++ to put in to binary folder where there is the game exe file.

My question is: what happen if I sign the dll without a trust organization certificate using only a private key ?

Is possible that an application can freeze if call a DLL not signed ? Or the trust organization certificate prevent UAC security popup only ?

I have compiled the open source project "x360ce" but the application freeze after call the xinput1_3.dll file compiled by me and signed with private key.

I need to buy a codesign certificate ? Or there is another solution ?

Comment: This doesn't really seem on-topic here (to me), but I cannot find a good close reason.

Comment: They could have written `if(!DllIsSigned()) FreezeProgram();` but it's not very likely. Probably you did something else wrong with the DLL.